# iOS - Color difference between NavigationBar Background and UIView Background

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

There is a color difference between NavigationBar and UIView. However I gave them the same color. How can I fix it with Swift programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the translucency on your NavigationBar.

[image]